# Recommend items to complete a set

Tags: recommender-system, frequent-itemsets

I'm trying to predict/recommend items to add to an incomplete basket. In this case, the basket is a project — e.g., you detect a customer trying to fix the AC in their car, hence you suggest things that they might be missing.

I've currently implemented a collaborative-filtering-based approach with customer-sessioning. This means that a customer might come back within 1-2 weeks and continue the purchase, which is considered the same session. This should capture the concept of "coming back for a missing item".

Overall, the results seem to make some sense, but I'm still not able to "detect projects". Expected outcome:

1. User buys `{item 1, item 2}` in the same session.
2. We've observed several sets containing those items in the same session, which might be weeks-long. The sets are `{ item 1, item 2, item 3}`, `{item 1, item 2, item 4}`, and `{item 1, item 2, item 3, item 6, item 7}`
3. The algorithm should rank these possible sets in terms of how likely they are, hopefully considering a vector of customer features and other covariates.

Any ideas on well-known architectures, proper performance metrics, or existing solutions available for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to recommend items to customers that they might need, based on the hidden pattern of a customer's basket might reveal.

Well, for a neural network to detect this kind of pattern is not quite efficient, most of this work should be done by your NLP co-workers. They could add tags to an item, and items with similar tags could be thus ranked with higher similarity.  Or input a pattern list to your model as a feature, and your model could detect the similar pattern of by this feature.

Generally speaking, you should not always rely on a model to automatically detect this kind of high level pattern, with not enough data. It's wise to give your model more information.

Thinking of training a model like driving a car to your destination, the input features are like the road signs which will lead your way, the more reliable signs you're given, the higher probability you will reach your final destination.